# Is there a list that describes which Chakras are located at which vertebrae?

Tags: chakras

After asking a question about the Manipura Chakra Tezz explained to me that it's important to distiguish the concept of the chakra as a region from the Kundalini entering area.

Given that the locations of the Chakra Jagarana correspond to locations on the spine, is there a list of which vertebrae are co-located with which Chakra at Susumna Nadi?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a discussion in the book 'The Serpent Power' by Sir John Woodroffe (Arthur Avalon).

> It is to be noted that, just as there are five centres (Cakras)
>   hereinafter described, the vertebral column itself is divided into
>   five regions, which commencing from the lowest, are the coccygeal,
>   consisting of four imperfect vertebrae, often united together into one
>   bone called the coccyx; the sacral region, consisting of five
>   vertebrae united together to form a single bone, the sacrum; the
>   lumbar region, or region of the loins, consisting of five vertebrae;
>   the dorsal region, or region of the back, consisting of twelve
>   vertebrae; and the cervical region, or the region of the neck,
>   consisting of seven vertebrae. As exhibited by segments, the cord
>   shows different characteristics in different regions. Roughly
>   speaking, these correspond to the regions assigned to the governing
>   control of the Muladhara, Svadhisthana, Manipura, Anahata and Visuddha
>   centres or Cakras or Lotuses (Padma).

The Serpent Power by Arthur Avalon (Sir John Woodroffe) Chapter V, The Centres or Lotuses (Cakra, Padma)

Comment: I understand the chakra region to cover multiple vertebrae but does the Chakra Jagarana also cover the space of multiple vertebrae? Most images of chakra's seem to contain smaller chakra's than a whole big region like the thorax.