# Why are chakra's frequently displayed as small points on the body and other times described as regions?

Tags: chakras

Most of the images of chakras that can be found on the internet show the chakra located at a specific point in the middle of the body. When I asked a request [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14902/is-there-a-list-that-describes-which-chakras-are-located-at-which-vertebrae) I got the answer that a chakra takes up more spaces and that the Anahata chakra for example fills the whole thoracic region and is thus much bigger than just the heart.

Where does the difference come from? Are there more specific names that point to the big region as opposed to the thing shown on popular images?

[eastern-spirituality.com](http://www.eastern-spirituality.com/glossary/spirituality-terms/c-definitions/chakra) for example talks about chakra's as points and not regions:

> In Sanātana/Hindu and tantric/yogic traditions and other belief systems, a chakra (IAST: cakra) is an energy point or node in the subtle body.